# Is there a better way to read complex binary data in C?

Tags: c, stdio, complex-numbers

I have written some code in C to read a binary file containing complex numbers. It works, but I am uncomfortable with the cast I need to perform. Is there a better way? Speed is critical in my program (I doubled the execution time by changing the code from C++ iostreams to C stdio functions). Can it also be made faster?

Here is my code:

```
#include<complex.h>
#include<errno.h>

#define spaceh 6912
#define Nc 3
#define dirac 4

...  ...

typedef double complex dcomplex;

long size;
size_t result;

char filename[84];
char* buffer;
dcomplex* zbuff;

int i, j, k, srccol, srcdir;
srcdir = 1;
srccol = 2;

/* allocate array dcomplex QM[dirac][Nc][space] on the heap */

sprintf(filename, "/<path>/file.%d.%d.bin", srcdir, srccol);

FILE* input;
input = fopen(filename, "rb");

if(readfile)
{
    fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(input);
    rewind(input);

    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    if(buffer == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Buffer allocation failed.", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    result = fread(buffer, 1, size, input);
    if(result != size)
    {
        fputs("File reading failed.", stderr);
        exit(2);
    }

    /* The cast I'm referring to */
    zbuff = (dcomplex*)buffer;
}
else
{
    printf("File was not successfully opened: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}

count = 0;
for(k = 0; k < space; k++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < Nc; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < dirac; i++)
        {
            QM[i][j][k] = convert_complex(zbuff(count));
            count++;
        }
    }
}

free(buffer);
fclose(input);
```

The convert_complex function reverses the byte order of a single complex number. I'm even more uncomfortable with that, but I don't want my question to become too large.

Comment: Any reason why you are not declaring buffer as `dcomplex* buffer;`

Comment: No reason, except perhaps because I originally received advice for the C++ version, which used a reinterpret_cast from a char* to a dcomplex*. Maybe in the C version I should have done it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the zbuff directly, without the need for intermediate buffer. For that you will need the following changes at appropriate places. In fread, instead of reading size 1, read sizeof(dcomplex). This should do it.

```
    //buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    zbuff = (dcomplex*)malloc(sizeof(dcomplex)*size);
    if(zbuff == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Buffer allocation failed.", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    result = fread(zbuff, sizeof(dcomplex), size, input);
    if(result != size)
    {
        fputs("File reading failed.", stderr);
        exit(2);
    }

    /* The cast I'm referring to */
    //zbuff = (dcomplex*)buffer;

    .......

    free(zbuff);
```

Replace all occurrences of 'buffer' with 'zbuff'.

Comment: @Marty_McFly - If it works for you, don't forget to 'upvote' my answer and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Answer accepted, but I think they disable upvoting to encourage me to become a fully registered user! :)

Comment: @Marty_McFly - I guess thats because you haven't got enough "reputation".

Comment: Note that `size` is still being obtained with `ftell()`, which gives a size in bytes, not in units of `sizeof(dcomplex)`.

Comment: That's right, when I accepted this answer, I replaced size with a constant, because I already know the exact number of complex entries in the file. But thanks anyway for noticing it.